# R coxph() warning: Loglik converged before variable - valid results for other variables?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I fit cox regressions and I am interested in the effect of a predictor x, which is the last variable in the model (variable 7). I include some variables like sex and age in the model, because I want to adjust the model for them.

Using R function coxph() gives me  the warning "Loglik converged **before** variable 3". In fact, I am not interested in variable 3, because it is just one of the variables I want to adjust for. But the word "before" makes me wonder whether this mean that results of all variables following variable 3 (which includs my predictor x) are not valid. Or are only the results of variable 3 affected?

This is the output:
[image: Output]

More information: Actually, I am running multiple cox regressions and the described warning occurs only in some of the models for variable 3. I do want to adjust for variable 3 and thus to keep it in the code.

There is some discussion about this warning(1), but I have not found an answer to my question so far. Thank you.

(1) For example, [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/174201.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369314/r-coxph-warning-loglik-converged-before-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for doing a search on prior answers. (And thanks for citing one of my answers :-) The warning message only applies to the control3 variable. The key to investigating the validity of the statistical inference about `predictorx` lies part of Therneau's answer that you cited. You are interested in one of the other variables and fortunately only one of your variables "exploded". That means you can do a LRT comparing the models with and without the variable(s) of interest to get a proper statistical result. The results are essentially saying there were no events in the subset of cases with a positive value of `control3 . I'm guessing that control3 is a 0/1 variable and if you looked at the table:

```
 with( your_data, table(control3, your_status_variable))
```

.... that you would find zero events in cases with control3 == 1.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Yes, there were no events in the subset of cases with a positive value of control3 and I knew that thanks to your response I cited. I did not mention that in my question because I wanted to keep it short. Maybe I should write in more detail in future. Thanks.